# Floating Point; Division vs Multiplication

Tags: math, floating-point

You have 2 functions;

```
f(x)= x(((x+1)^(1/2))-(x^(1/2)))    
g(x)= x/(((x+1)^(1/2))+(x^(1/2)))
```

Which one is more accurate?

Side note: If you could explain why, that would really help me out, I have a feeling it's f(x) as there isn't a denominator but I'm not 100% certain.

Comment: Waaaay off-topic for SO, try [math.stackexchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: Hello Claire, StackExchange is splited into multiple pages, focusing on different subjects. One of them is [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/). You should ask your question there.

Comment: Thanks guys, I will do just that

Comment: @ClaireBlackman Assuming the question is asked in the context of IEEE-754 floating-point arithmetic, what range of `x` being considered? I am asking to establish whether subtractive cancellation is an issue or not. It seems likely that `f()` will suffer from subtractive cancellation.

Comment: @njuffa where x=500. It's weird as f(x) = g(x) but I assume when it comes down to rounding errors

Comment: @ClaireBlackman: Mathematically equivalent expressions are rarely equivalent when evaluated in finite-precision floating-point arithmetic; see my answer.

Comment: @TheBlueDog Mathematically, these are identical.  math.se would stop caring at that point.  OP's question is which one suffers less from rounding errors when evaluated with floating point arithmetic.  I don't see how this wouldn't be SO.

Comment: OP reposted to http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72801 (which is still different than math.se, and I would still say this question best fits SO).

Answer (score 5):

Floating-point arithmetic is quite different from real mathematics. In particular, floating-point arithmetic is not associative or distributive. Therefore mathematically equivalent expressions are not necessarily equivalent when evaluated with finite-precision floating-point arithmetic. This is the case even when individual operations, such as addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, and square root produce correctly rounded results, as required by the [IEEE-754 floating-point standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point).

In this case `g()` will be much more accurate than `f()` on average, and also for the specific case of `x = 500`. The reason is that `f()` suffers from subtractive cancellation. This occurs during effective subtraction of two floating-point numbers that are almost identical in magnitude. The leading digits cancel during the subtraction, leaving only a few remaining trailing digits that enter into subsequent computation. Also, any rounding error accumulated in the trailing digits of the original operands being subtracted may be magnified by subsequent computation. An expanded explanation with example can be found in [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance).

In this case, `sqrt(x+1)` and `sqrt(x)` are almost the same magnitude, in particular as the magnitude of `x` increases. Using the example of `x = 500` and employing IEEE-754 single-precision arithmetic, we find:

```
x = 500   f(x) = 0x1.659ae0p+3 (11.175156)   reference = 0x1.659798p+3 (11.174755)
x = 500   g(x) = 0x1.659798p+3 (11.174755)   reference = 0x1.659798p+3 (11.174755)
```

The error in `f(500)` is 420 [ulps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place), while `g(500)` delivers the correctly rounded single-precision result.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are there values for which `f` is more accurate?  Not just "on average"?

Comment: OT: Weird that my answer turned into a community wiki automagically. @Teepeemm: Yes, from a cursory check with random IEEE-754 single-precision arguments, numerous such cases exist. For example: `x=0x1.6fa276p-2 (3.59018177e-1); f(x)=0x1.a09844p-3 (2.03415424e-1); g(x)=0x1.a09846p-3 (2.03415439e-1); ref=0x1.a09844p-3 (2.03415425e-1); ulperr(f)=6.71231e-2; ulperr(g)=9.32877e-1`